# Default home page setting in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a scenario where I have hosted my Liferay application on 123.12.12.12(suppose).

Whenever a user hits this IP,

- user sees the login page i.e. **123.12.12.12/web/guest/home**.
- Same happens when user's session is alive i.e. If user is already
  logged in and hits **123.12.12.12**, user lands to
  `123.12.12.12/web/guest/home` where login portlet shows `"you are already logged in."`.

What I want is that, if user is already logged in then:

- he should get redirected to the application home page
  (**123.12.12.12/web/abc/home**)
- which I have set in ***lastPath*** using a hook and where have overridden
  run method of ***Action*** class.
- When user logs in, he/she gets redirected to
  **123.12.12.12/web/abc/home** successfully.
- I need the same when user hits `123.12.12.12` even if he/she is
  logged in.

I am using **Liferay 6.0.6 CE on Tomcat 6.0.29**.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the ideal solution but a workaround -
In your login.jsp write a script and check if the user is signed in or not. If signed in then redirect to your home page

```
<script>
//on  doc ready
if("<%= themeDisplay.isSignedIn()%>") 
{
    location.href="/web/abc/home";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Atin, this kind of implementation would take the flow into an infinite loop where if login portlet is included on all pages. And even if otherwise, there will always be a double redirection (an extra reload) whenever this snippet is implemented.